# Can atoms capture beta particles or secondary electrons into their orbits and become anions?

Tags: electrons, radiation, ions

Since beta-particles are just free-moving electrons, shouldn't they be caught by strongly-electronegative atoms and thus create anions?
Why do they instead create more cations by knocking other electrons out of their orbits?
Does it, perhaps, depend on the speed of electron: i.e., slow-moving, non-ionizing electrons are more likely to be caught by atoms?

Comment: Chuck this Wikipedia article : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_ion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beta particle energies are of order $10^5$ eV, which is vastly greater than typical electron affinities of order $1$ eV. The beta electron is not going to end up bound to another atom until it's had a chance to dissipate the unwanted $99,999$ eV. The energy is typically dissipated by colliding with other atoms and ionising them.

Comment: Thanks. So basically, all beta particles will end up being caught by atoms, but not before they dissipate their energy?
Also, am I right to understand that secondary electrons can be caught immediately because they are slow?

Comment: Secondary electrons will have a large range of energies because their energy depends on whether the beta particle scored a full hit or just a glancing blow. Some will have low enough energies to be captured immediately while others will have much higher energies.